# Generating SQL SP checksum

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

does anyone know of a way to generate some kind of checksum for each Stored Procedure on a server, in order to be able to compare them to other SP's on different servers?

Regards,

Jeroen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could;

```
SELECT 
    ROUTINE_NAME, 
    HASHBYTES('SHA1', ROUTINE_DEFINITION)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(ROUTINE_NAME), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
```

Comment: Just tried this and it seems to do exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jebus89 - Of course, it all goes a bit pear-shaped if you've got long stored procedures, since `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` only contains the first 4000 characters.